# Merging Razor with Jquery for autocomplete function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

im using this guide http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data and what little i know of C# and razor to try autocomplete 3 textboxes whenever one of them is picked.

so if i type in the partno and choose one from the drop down list, item name, desc and ID are populated. and the same if i type in any other field.

i have created a class and put it in a list with the items in

```
var varItems = new List<Item>();
            varItems = db.Items.Select(tbl => new Item
                    {
                            ID = tbl.ID,
                            Name = tbl.Name,
                            PartNo = tbl.PartNo,
                            Description = tbl.Description
                    }).ToList();
```

then sent that in a viewbag

```
ViewBag.Items = var.items;
```

then in the view

```
   $( "#Name" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: @ViewBag.Items,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#Name" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#Name" ).val( ui.item.Name );
            $( "#PartNo" ).val( ui.item.PartNo );
            $( "#Description" ).html( ui.item.Description );
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it doesnt like the viewbag being there. im guessing i have to do some sort of loop to produce something like the below?

```
var projects = [
      {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
      }
    ];
```

if so how do i loop my list to create the above?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
source: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Items));
```

This would encode your Items to json and it should work.

Comment: Im getting an empty drop down appear under the name field?

Comment: Thats probably other error, can you confirm that the json was generated correctly? check the Html source.

Comment: i think it looks ok yeah: source: [{"ID":1,"Name":"HP DL360p","PartNo":" 670638-425","Description":""},{"ID":2,"Name":"Samsung 840 Pro 256GB","PartNo":"","Description":"256GB SSD"}]

Comment: then if you change it for a static json you would have the same problem you have now, its not the enconding or managing the viewbag but the jquery you are ussing. Maybe create other question and use a jsfiddle.net to show whats happening and someone can help you.

Comment: ok ill give that a go, thanks for your help with the json thingy :)

Comment: if you create the jsfiddle let me know and I can take a look at it.

Comment: great thanks, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116623/autocomplete-not-showing-options-until-backspace-and-text-is-not-visible