# autocomplete, not showing options until backspace and text is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

ive created a JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8nzty/
code here:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".items").click(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
    var items = [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "HP DL360p", "PartNo": " 670638-425", "Description": "" }, { "ID": 2, "Name": "Samsung 840 Pro 256GB", "PartNo": "", "Description": "256GB SSD" }, { "ID": 3, "Name": "HP MSA P2000", "PartNo": "AW568A", "Description": "" }, { "ID": 4, "Name": "HP BL460c G6", "PartNo": null, "Description": "HP G6 Blade" }]
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: items,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
            $("#PartNo").val(ui.item.PartNo);
            $("#Description").val(ui.item.Description);
            return false;
        }
    });
})
</script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span><input name="Name" class="items ui-autocomplete-input valid" id="Name" type="text" value="Item Name" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input name="PartNo" class="items" id="PartNo" type="text" value="Part Number"></td>
            <td><input name="Description" class="items" id="Description" type="text" value="Description"></td>
            <td><input name="cmd" class="blue-button" id="btnAddItem" type="submit" value="+"></td>
            <td><input name="cmd" class="blue-button" id="btnRemoveItem" type="submit" value="-"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Whats supposed to happen:
I type h and see a list of items beginning containing h
I click an option
part no and description are autofilled

whats happening:
i type h, nothing happens
i hit backspace a dropdown appears with none visible text (maybe its white?)
on mouseover i see text appear in the name box, click one and its autofilled as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nzty/2/)

You almost got it.  The issue is that you don't provide a way to show the options on the screen.  You're using an array of JSON objects, so the widget needs to be told what data and how to display it.

```
$("#Name").autocomplete({
  //existing widget settings
})
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
  .append( "<a>" + item.Name + "<br>" + item.Description + "</a>" )
  .appendTo( ul );
};
```

to the end of the `autocomplete` widget solves the issue.

Comment: ah i see, but when i type h still i dont see anything with h, i have to hit backspace to see the options, does that happen with yours too?

Comment: Hi there, did you see the above? the autocomplete doesnt start when you start to type, you have to type hit backspace back to nothing then the menu appears, Thanks for your help